# Smartphones network strength identification from http headers in java?

Tags: java, servlets, mobile, tapestry

I am Developing a web application in Tapestry Java & am running it in smart-phone browsers. I want to identify the calling device network signal strength (i.e., just whether it is 2g or 3g ..) Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that browsers don't provide access to the signal strength (either through a javascript API or as request headers).

If you want to guage how fast the data speed is, you could send a request for an image in javascript and time how long it takes to download. You could then save this in a cookie or pass the value serverside and store in the HTTPSession.

eg:

```
var download = new Image();
var startTime;
download.onload = function () {
    var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    var duration = endTime - startTime
    alert("Download took " + duration);
}
startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
download.src = "http://foo.bar.com/myImage.jpg?random=" + Math.random();
```

If you really want to access the signal strength on the device, I think you'll need to install an app on the phone. I'm guessing that [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) has a javascript API to access this value.

Comment: I can't get you, Am asking for signal strength!

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to test if they had a fast connection (3g) or a slower connection (2g). I've updated my answer.